# Syntax errors, infinite loops and a bunch of formatting issues

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, calculation

I've been attempting to code this program for the past half a month or so but I'm stumped and I need to make substantial progress soon to meet my deadline, any help/advice would be appreciated. Apologies for the bad formatting, thanks for any help you can provide.

```
 def main():
 
     choice = printMenu()
     print(choice)


def menu():


  print("NRAS Eligibility Calculator")


  print("[1] Display Household Income Limits")



  print("[2] Calculate Total Income")


  print("[3] Calculate Eligibility")


  print("[4]: Exit")
        


def choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))



while choice !=0:


 elif choice== 1:



        print("$52,324")



 elif choice== 2:


        def add_num(a,b):


         sum=a+b;


        return sum; 


        num1=int(input("income from source 1: "))
        num2=int(input("income from source 2 :"))


        print("Your total income is",add_num(num1,num2))


 elif choice== 3:


         def add_num(a,b):


         sum=a+b;


        return sum; 



        num1=int(input("income from source 1: "))


        num2=int(input("income from source 2 :"))


        if sum <= "52,324"


        print("You're eligible for NRAS!")


        else


        print ("Sadly, you're not eligible.")







 elif choice== 4:


        quit()


 else:


         print("Invalid option.")



print("Thank you for using this calculator.")
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code is doing a bit more in detail. And what is the point of `def add_num()` 2 times? There are a lot of issues here.

Comment: you should correct your formatting... apologizing for doesn't make it readable

Comment: your code isn't understandable what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected most of the mistakes and the code works fine. I have also added comments to highlight the changes I made.

But there a lot of questionable things that were going on in this code. I suggest you to look into python syntax properly.

```
def add_num(a,b):
    sum = a+b

    return sum

def menu():
    print("NRAS Eligibility Calculator")
    print("[1] Display Household Income Limits")
    print("[2] Calculate Total Income")
    print("[3] Calculate Eligibility")
    print("[4] Exit")

    ch = int(input('Enter your choice : ')) # added a variable to read the choice.

    return ch # then return this choice when this function is called.

def choice(choice):
    while choice != 0:
        if choice== 1: # changed the elif to if.
            print("$52,324")
            break # added a break due to infinite loop

        elif choice == 2:
            num1=int(input("income from source 1: "))
            num2=int(input("income from source 2 :"))

            print("Your total income is",add_num(num1,num2))
            
        elif choice == 3:
            num1=int(input("income from source 1: "))
            num2=int(input("income from source 2 :"))

            SUM = add_num(num1, num2) # calling the add_num function here.

            if SUM <= 52324: # changed this to int type instead of a string.
                print("You're eligible for NRAS!")
            else:
                print ("Sadly, you're not eligible.")

        elif choice == 4:
            quit()
            
        else:
            print("Invalid option.")

    print("Thank you for using this calculator.")

def main():
    ch = menu()
    choice(ch)


if __name__ == "__main__": # this is how you call a main() in python.
    main()
```